# How to add computation (eg log and sqrt root) to keras vgg16 before softmax layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am implementing the improved bilinear pooling (http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/bcnn/docs/improved_bcnn.pdf) and I want to add computation (eg log and square root) before softmax layer to my model, which is fine tuned from keras vgg16 .
How can I do that?

```
vgg_16 = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
vgg_16.layers.pop()

My_Model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg_16.layers:
    My_Model.add(layer)

for layer in My_Model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
# I want to add this function on top of my model then feed the result to a softmax layer
# 

def BILINEAR_POOLING(bottom1, bottom2, sum_pool=True):
    assert(np.all(bottom1.shape[:3] == bottom2.shape[:3]))
    batch_size, height, width = bottom1.shape[:3]
    output_dim = bottom1.shape[-1] * bottom2.shape[-1]

    bottom1_flat = bottom1.reshape((-1, bottom1.shape[-1]))
    bottom2_flat = bottom2.reshape((-1, bottom2.shape[-1]))

    output = np.empty((batch_size*height*width, output_dim), np.float32)
    for n in range(len(output)):
        output[n, ...] = np.outer(bottom1_flat[n], bottom2_flat[n]).reshape(-1)
    output = output.reshape((batch_size, height, width, output_dim))

    if sum_pool:
        output = np.sum(output, axis=(1, 2))
    return output
```

Comment: I am using vgg16 with conv layers only (include top = false). I wrote a code to flatten the final tensor to a 2D tansor then apply log and sqrt on it. But how can add this functions to my model? Can use the keras lambda to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was only adding a keras lambda layer
as follow

```
My_Model.add(Lambda(BILINEAR_POOLING,output_shape=[512,512]))
```